# Unit Test Angular 6

Tags: unit-testing, angular6

I have two buttons with inputs, like this:

```
 <div class="input-group col-5 align-self-center">
      <input id="endeDate" class="form-control" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" name="endeDate"
             [minDate]="minDate" [markDisabled]="disableWeekend" [class.is-invalid]="checkValidity('dateEnd')"
             ngbDatepicker #endeDate="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="dateEnd" (focus)="endeDate.toggle()">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary calendar" (click)="endeDate.toggle()" type="button">
          <fa-icon icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>


<div class="input-group col-5 align-self-center">
      <input id="startDate" class="form-control" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" name="startDate"
             [minDate]="minDate" [markDisabled]="disableWeekend" [class.is-invalid]="checkValidity('dateStart')"
             ngbDatepicker #startDate="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="dateStart" (focus)="startDate.toggle()">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary calendar" (click)="startDate.toggle()" type="button">
          <fa-icon icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I need to write unit tests. Unit test has to check datepicker.

```
  it('check Validation field Ende', () => {
       let datepicker = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button').endeDate.toggle();
       expect(document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu.show')).toBeNull();
       datepicker.click();
       expect(document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu.show')).not.toBeNull();
  });
```

But in first and second it opened the same first button.
I tried also this:

```
   let datepicker = 
   fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=endeDate]'));
   datepicker.nativeElement.click();
```

but it doesn't work. 
Have somebody another Idea

Answer (score 0):

Typically - with Angular being more of the UI component - I will not recommend doing this as a "unit test" from inside Angular. This is more of an end-to-end test you are performing, so why not make use of something like Selenium?

Also - you are selecting the element by CSS - highly recommend you do it by ID instead.